# Take a certain string in JSON and put in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms, richtextbox

I have a simple program in C # Windows Form, I would need that by inserting a json it fetches the string after:  "htmlMailBytes":"        and before     "}, "errorInfo": {}}}
can help me please?`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(richTextBox1.Text);
        richTextBox2.Text = "" + System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
    }
    catch (Exception errorMsg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(errorMsg.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try looking into [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which can be installed with NuGet. Otherwise some string magic with `Substring` and `IndexOf` could work.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Newtonsoft.Json` package to you project as described in comment above by @Jack T. Spades. Then you can make the following to deserialize the JSON to the your object type:

```cs
string js = "{ \"htmlMailBytes\": \"email @server.com\", \"errorInfo\": \"data\"}"; // Some string for the test
if (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultObject>(js) is ResultObject result)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + result.HtmlMailBytes); 
} 

public partial class ResultObject
{
    [JsonProperty("htmlMailBytes")]
    public string HtmlMailBytes { get; set; }
}
```